# How do I properly pass a two dimensional int array to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, function-call

I'm a newbie when it comes to C++ and coding in general as this is only my second course. For my assignment, I have to code a program for a memory game where the user selects cards in a 2D array to try to match them. Right now, however, I'm struggling to get my function call for initializeBoard() to compile without an error. The message I get is:

```
    main.cpp:63:3: error: no matching function for call to
       'initializeBoard'
      initializeBoard(gameBoard, rows);

    main.cpp:35:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known
       conversion from 'int [rows][col]' to 'int (*)[col]' for 1st
       argument
```

A simplified copy of my code is written below containing the lines I believe are involved in the error.

```
    int rows = 4;
    int col = 4;

    void initializeBoard(int gameBoard[][col], int rows);

    int main()
    {
       int players;
       string p1Name, p2Name, p3Name, p4Name, p5Name;

       rules();

       getPlayers(players, p1Name, p2Name, p3Name, p4Name, p5Name);

       if (2 < players && players < 5)
       {
         rows = 6;
         col = 6;
       }
       else if (players == 5)
       {
         rows = 8;
         col = 8;
       }

       int (gameBoard)[rows][col];

       initializeBoard(gameBoard, rows); // I get an error saying there is no matching function for call to 'initializeBoard'
       }
```

Could someone explain to me where I am going wrong and help me find a solution to the issue?

Comment: Pass a pointer to the first cell, and the maximum rows and maximum columns.  This assumes the array is contiguous slots.

Comment: So I need to pass the rows and col variables as int parameters separate from the array then? And yes, the end result should look more like a table than actual separate cards

Comment: Not exactly.  The function receiving the 2d array needs to know the capacity of the array, in rows and columns.

Comment: Note: C++ doesn't have Standard support for Variable Length Arrays like `int (gameBoard)[rows][col];` so you might not like what you get. What I generally do is work in 1 dimensional arrays all nicely wrapped up in a class that hides the math that converts the 1D array in to 2 dimensions and carries around the dimensions so no one else has to. [Here's a pretty good, simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const int rows = 4;
> const int col = 4;
>
> void initializeBoard(int gameBoard[][col], int rows);
> ```

Here you've defined a function that will take a 2D array (by pointer) in which the second dimension is 4. The number of rows is not fixed, but you're passing that dimension as the second parameter.

It looks like in `main` you're trying to pass a 2D array that doesn't have columns (or second dimension) of size 4. Hence the compiler error. The second dimension must be 4 in order to call `initializeBoard`.

Although your compiler is allowing you to declare a variable sized 2D array, this [isn't allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343850/variable-length-array-overhead-in-c) by the C++ standard. It's a compiler specific extension.

Instead of using raw arrays like in C, you could use a vector of vectors. That will allow you to pass a 2D matrix:

```
#include <vector>

void initializeBoard(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &gameBoard);
```

Alternatively, you could convert your function into a template function that will deduce the dimensions for you:

```
template<size_t row, size_t col>
void initializeBoard(int (&gameBoard)[row][col])
{
 ...
}
```

However, the array dimensions should be known at compile time. If they're not, you're better off using a vector of vectors.