# C++, Array size must be an const expression

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently reading the book "C++ Primer" by Lappman. In page 113 It says

> The number of elements in an array is part of the array’s type. As a result, the dimension must
>   be known at compile time, which means that the dimension must be a constant
>   expression.

In addition it says we can't do something like this

```
unsigned cnt  = 43; //not an const expression
string bad[cnt]; // error
```

But it's not true, I compiled it without any problem, I can do even something like this

```
int i;
cin >> i;
get_size(i);

void get_size(int size) {
  int arr[size];
  cout << sizeof (arr);
}
```

And it works well, So why every book say that array size must be known at compile time? Or it must be const expression?

Comment: @juan: If using Stack Overflow, try the _answer section_ to post an answer to a question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was picking a suitable duplicate. Difficult to choose when there are so many.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because those books are teaching you C++.

It *is* true, in C++.

What you are using is a non-standard extension provided by GCC specifically, called *Variable Length Arrays*.

If you turn on all your compiler warnings, which you should always do, you will be informed about this during the build.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as VLAs (variable length arrays), and they are in fact [standard in C99](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=215), although they are not always considered acceptable and are [not required to be supported by the compiler as of C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array). GCC allows them as an extension in C++ code.

If you want to do some experimenting then you can use `-std=standard`, `-ansi` and `-pedantic` options.

You can also refer to this question: [Why does a C/C++ compiler need know the size of an array at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341570/why-does-a-c-c-compiler-need-know-the-size-of-an-array-at-compile-time) where the accepted answer has a good explanation about it.

Comment: It's discouraged in C++, though. Highly unportable and unnecessary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:- Yes thats correct, thats why I added the C99 part.

Comment: I'm just saying this is a bit misleading. You could emphasise that it's not "very much acceptable and in fact standard" as far as _this_ question goes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:- Updated that.