# The difference of function assigning to variable in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo() { return 0; }
int a = foo();
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The code above can not be complied because of

> From section 3.5.7 Initialization of the C standard:
>
> > All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration or in an initializer list for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be constant expressions.

```
#include <iostream>
int foo() { return 0; }
int a = foo();
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't know why it can be complied in C++ without using `constexpr`

I want to mention that my main question is why it can be complied in C++ without using `constexpr`

Comment: So basically you're asking, why your cooler can cool and why your notebook cannot, right?

Comment: Despite the similiarities, they're two completely different languages, always keep that in mind!

Comment: Why can I iterate a string like `for c in "Hello": ...` in Python and not in C?

Comment: @Olaf: You probably meant, why can you [do it in C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/147563394dfcf03c) and not in C.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I strongly doubt that is valid C++ syntax. No, I mean OP compares two different languages, thus the question could as well be asking why Python code does not compile as C. Comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to learn/understand C++ and noting the similarity between C and C++ asks this question to understand the differences and how C++ does things (because it is a different language from C).

Comment: @callyalater Thank you, that's why I ask this question. It seems that my expression is not good enough.

Comment: @Olaf: What on Earth makes you doubt the syntax? Hello.'

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I answered in context of your comment to my comment. `for c in "Hello": ...` on Earth is certainly not valid C++. Not sure how is is on Gallifrey, though.

Comment: @Olaf: So, when you wrote "THAT", in response to my comment, you meant your Python example and not the C++ example I linked to? That's, like, at the very least an **actively misleading** comment. Borderline untruthful.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't think so. You clearly commented on part of my comment, so how would I know the related part of your comment means the text in the question? Maybe you should power up your sarcasm sensors? Or _at the very least_ just try to understand what other posters mean, instead of assuming bad intention. "No, I mean OP compares two different languages, thus the question could as well be asking why **Python** code does not compile as C. Comparing apples and oranges." should have been clear enough.

Comment: @Olaf: What the f? You **don't think** you referred to  your Python code, when you wrote *that* in response to my link to C++ code. Then logically you referred to the C++ code after all. But logic doesn't apply here, does it? The original comment was just free association on your part, reflecting familiarity with Python and less familiarity with C++, and you don't want to admit that.

Answer (score 4):

C++ is a different programming language. It has different rules than C. For one, C++ supports non-constant initializers for static variables. They are executed prior to `main()`. That's why the code compiles and works in C++.

Comment: Most compilers will execute the initialization before main, but it is implementation defined.

Comment: @callyalater So the initializers might not execute before `main()` does? Can you cite the standard on that?

Comment: Section 3.6.2(4). It is quoted in my answer below.

Comment: @callyalater Thinking about this, I would say that most variables are indeed initialized on first use due to the binary image being loaded lazily (i.e. on page fault).

Comment: That makes sense. It seems like that it could be related to how a compiler does memory access optimizations, but that is just a guess.

Comment: I wonder what g++ does in this case. Do you know or know where I could find out?

Comment: @callyalater I have no idea. I'm not a C++ programmer either.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `int a` is a variable with `static` storage duration.

According to the C++ Standard, Section 3.6.2 (4),

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with `static` storage
>   duration is done before the first statement of `main`. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time
>   after the first statement of `main`, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable
>   defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Depending on your compiler, `a` might get initialized before `main` or it will get initialized before its first use in main. (Most compilers do the former, because it tends to be easier to implement.)

So, in your example, `int a = foo();` is declaring and initializing a variable with `static` storage duration, which is allowed in the C++ standard.

Comment: When used `int a[foo()+10];` instead of `int a = foo();`I got error: variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope. I know that's why we need `constexpr`. However, why it would fail? Is that global array with `static` storage duration? Thank you.

Comment: That is a little different because it introduces arrays into the mix which need to be effectively constant at compile time (though many C++ compilers provide added functionality that relaxes the `constexpr` requirement for array sizes).

Comment: Arrays in C++ are laid out contiguously in memory which means that it's size must be known at compile time to reserve the proper amount of space. If `foo()` returned different values depending on execution, there would be no way to fix an array length in memory because it could vary. The compiler has no way to know if the return value from `foo` is effectively const and so it raises an error at compile time. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4341919/4975646) for another question explains a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason that C++ can compile your code even without the 'constexpr' attribute on your declaration of `foo()` is that you have not declared `int a` to be a `constexpr`. Therefore, the compiler doesn't need to know the value of `a`, and it can be initialized at runtime.

Comment: @Alf Thanks for the edit. Darn autocorrect. I typed `constexpr` and just didn't notice when it got "corrected." :P